# Pass JavaScript array to cherrypy with AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, arrays, cherrypy

I'm trying to send an array to cherrypy but it turns out empty.

This is my js file. I've checked and the array gets filled as it should.

```
$(function () {
$('#mark-read').on('click', function (e) {

    alert_ids = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=alert-cb]:checked").each(function() {
        alert_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'markasread',
      data: { alerts: alert_ids },
      traditional: true,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data);            
      }
    });
});
```

});

This is the cherrypy part (I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065913/how-to-send-a-javascript-array-to-cherrypy) as a guideline)

```
@cherrypy.expose    
def markasread(self, **alerts_ids):

    """ Mark alerts as read """

    a_ids = alerts_ids.pop('alerts[]', [])
    alerts.mark_as_read(a_ids)

    return json.dumps(a_ids)
```

And this is the function being called from the python code above

```
def mark_as_read(alerts):
  alerts_file = ET.parse(ALERTS_FILE)
  root = alerts_file.getroot()  

  for a_id in alerts:
    alert = root.find("./alert[@id='" + a_id + "']")
    alert.set('status', 'watched')

  alerts_file.write(ALERTS_FILE)
```

My goal here is to save data to an xml file. I've managed to save to the xml file with similar code. The problem is that 'alerts' in the for loop is empty, which means that the array didn't pass with the ajax call (at least that's my guess).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `$.ajax` simply with `data: {alerts: alert_ids}` instead of `data: JSON.stringify({alerts: alert_ids})`.

Also, remove the `contentType : "application/json",` line. CherryPy exposed methods expect form-urlencoded format, not json.

If you set `traditional: true`, you must not add the braces after the `alerts` parameter in CherryPy, otherwise you must add them.

Comment: No. I still get nothing on the python side (getting the default []).

Comment: Found another problem in your code, see the last part of my edited answer.

Comment: I've updated my code (and also in the question) to your suggestions, but still I get [] from a_ids in the cherrypy part...

Comment: Now you have also added `traditional: true`. If you do that, you don't need to write the braces after `alerts` in CherryPy, i.e. you write only `a_ids = alerts_ids.pop('alerts', [])` in CherryPy. Without the `traditional: true`, i.e. with `traditional: false`, you need the braces after `alerts`. You must use one fix or the other, but not both at the same time.